# Sub-query Join Error

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

> "Using subquery, list all product (product number, brand, and category) whose overall number of orders (containing that product) is greater than 500"

Before sub-query I tried using a join:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT.BRAND,PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
FROM PRODUCT JOIN ORDERLINE
ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO = ORDERLINE.PRODUCT_NO
WHERE SUM(ORDERLINE_NO) >= 500 ;
```

And got the following error;

> ```
> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
> 00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 28 Column: 6
> ```

Comment: Could someone help me convert this answer by John Woo to a Sub query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there but since you've used *aggregate* function, you must  have a  `GROUP BY` clause and a `HAVING` clause to filter the aggregated result:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO, 
       PRODUCT.BRAND,
       PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY 
FROM PRODUCT JOIN ORDERLINE ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO = ORDERLINE.PRODUCT_NO 
GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO, 
       PRODUCT.BRAND,
       PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
HAVING COUNT(ORDERLINE_NO) >= 500 ;
```

And use `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()`.

Comment: Could you please guide me to change this to a sub query? Thank you very much @John

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

not sure if this is what you want

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT.BRAND,PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
FROM PRODUCT JOIN ORDERLINE
ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO = ORDERLINE.PRODUCT_NO
GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT.BRAND,PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
HAVING COUNT(ORDERLINE_NO) >= 500 ;
```